# Using variables by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

We have `Myclass &funcref();` and `Myclass func();` and assign the return value to a variable (not a variable reference). If I understand correctly we use the copy constructor in both cases. The only difference is that `funcref()` returns a reference, and we copy over what is refers to into our object, while in `func()`, we copy the object while returning.

If we assign it to a variable reference, only `func()` still needs a copy constructor.

I hope everything until now is correct - if not, please point out my missunderstanding.

Now my question:

It seems like whether we assign the return value of `func()` to a variable, or a variable reference, it does not change anything at all? Is there any case in which those two will differ? At least when they are assigned, it seems like the process is the same, but I may be wrong.

In code:

```
class My_class {
    //Anything may be here
};

My_class func();
My_class &funcref();

int main() {
    My_class a = func(); //Copy operator used?
    const My_class &b = func(); //Why does this need to be constant? Also, this uses copy operator, right?
    My_class c = funcref(); //Copy operator used?
    My_class &d = funcref(); //Here, we do not need a copy operator, right?
}
```

Main question: Except for b being const, is there any difference between `a` and  `b`? Both seem to be on the stack of main, so do they differ in any way?

Comment: Do you mean `Myclass& funcref();` in your first sentence?

Comment: `&Myclass funcref();` this does not look like valid C++. You really should provide a [mcve] to illustrate what your question is

Comment: Fixed, sorry. I wasn't sure how to provide one, as the answer might be different for every implementation of My_class, and I was hoping for one that can cover all cases.

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Can you show some real code, and explain, using the shown code as an example, what your question is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Understood, I have added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I understand correctly we use the copy constructor in both cases.

Not quite. In C++11, move constructor will be used in case of `Myclass func()` (and compiler is allowed to optimise the copy / move away).

Since C++17, there is neither move nor copy in case of `Myclass func()`.

> Is there any case in which those two will differ?

It is somewhat unclear what cases you are asking about. There is a differenceiIn the case where the function returns a reference.

> if I am calling any function that returns a non-reference, should I assign the output as a reference, or not as a reference?

Typically, you should use an object variable because that is simpler and doesn't involve the cognitive load of having to understand reference bound temporary lifetime extension rules.

Only case I can think of where reference variable for prvalue makes sense is a template context where the called function might return a reference, or a non-reference object that acts as a reference wrapper. I believe that case is the reason why temporary lifetime extension exists.

Comment: You are right, thank you! I totally missed that the move constructor would be used there. That said, I was wondering if I am calling any function that returns a non-reference, should I assign the output as a reference, or not as a reference? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you maybe also know why my variable b needs to be constant?

Comment: @Aperonamos Because temporaries cannot be bound to lvalue references to non-const.